# WPF how to set focus to an entire datagrid on combobox selection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a 3 datagrids under 3 tabsitems. Based on a combobox selection, I want one of the datagrids to be focused on regardless of which datagrid the user has opened. Any help?

Comment: Show us what did you try yet or provide some details with an example

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you are trying to do while maintaining the mvvm pattern, you can use attached properties or do it in a converter with the tab item as a parameter.

Else, you can use the selectionChanged event and set the correct tab item for your data grid there.